# postgresql rename index

Tags: postgresql, index

I want to understand how safe is the rename command:

```
ALTER INDEX old_name RENAME TO new_name;
```

The index was created by command(for the foreign key column):

```
CREATE INDEX old_name ON table_t1 (user_id);
```

Does it mean simple update in the postgres system tables or do much more operations. I try to find it in the docs but unsuccess.

Comment: @McNets thank you for help with the question details, no it is index without any features.

Comment: @McNets: that link is irrelevant for Postgres as it is about SQL Server and Postgres does not have clustered indexes to begin with. (plus it's about **dropping** an index, not about renaming it)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterindex.html)

> The RENAME form changes the name of the index (...) There is **no effect on the stored data**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So yes, this is a simple update to the system catalog.

The statement sill needs an exclusive lock on the table if I'm not mistaken, but the lock will only be held for a very short period.

Comment: The exclusive lock requirement is removed in PostgreSQL 12, yet I wrote a function allowing to do it for older versions as well. Enjoy: https://github.com/kouber/pg_utils/blob/master/rename_index.sql